# Is there a specific word for a snow patch?

Tags: single-word-requests

Snow patch is a compound noun. I was wondering if there was a specific word for a snow patch ? To be honest it just surprises me that there isn't a specific word for it since it would be such an ubiquitous natural formation in pre-industrial times, especially since the word for it in my native language is also a compound noun.

Comment: Can you describe what you think a 'snow patch' is? That might help with you search for synonyms that are single words. Also have you tried using an automated translation for the word in your native language?

Comment: @mitch yes, like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/Aonach_Mor_Protalus.jpg/220px-Aonach_Mor_Protalus.jpg

Comment: Can you describe in words? Also, you should edit and show any of your research in the original question.

Comment: In parts of the US that would be called a "glacier".